# Httpd returning 503 Service Unavailable with mod_proxy for Tomcat 8

Tags: apache, tomcat

I'm trying to integrate Tomcat with Apache. My aim is to redirect all the requests with
`http://localhost/myapp` to `http://localhost:8080`

I followed this guide: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/proxy-howto.html

My `httpd.conf` looks like this:

```
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf
LoadModule proxy_module  modules/mod_proxy.so

ProxyPass         /myapp  http://localhost:8080 retry=0 timeout=5
ProxyPassReverse  /myapp  http://localhost:8080
```

My server.xml in apache-tomcat looks like this:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" proxyPort="80" />
```

Now when I try the url `http://localhost/myapp`, it gives `503 Service Unavailable` error.

Both Tomcat and Apache are up and running. The URL `http://localhost:8080` works fine.

Can there be an issue with file permissions?

For `tomcat` the user and group are `root/root` and for `httpd`, the user and group are `apache/apache`

Am I missing something or am I doing it wrong?

Httpd version is 2.4.6 and Tomcat's version is 8.0

The httpd error logs:

```
[proxy:error] [pid 19905] (13)Permission denied: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 (localhost) failed

[proxy:error] [pid 19905] AH00959: ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (localhost) for 0s

[proxy_http:error] [pid 19905] [client ::1:51615] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: localhost
```

**Solved!**

The answer is here: http://sysadminsjourney.com/content/2010/02/01/apache-modproxy-error-13permission-denied-error-rhel/

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I found this http://sysadminsjourney.com/content/2010/02/01/apache-modproxy-error-13permission-denied-error-rhel/ which solved the issue

Comment: Better you remove retry and timeout option and check

Comment: FWIW, I was getting the 503 error but with a timeout. Turned out that for my `ProxyPass*` lines I couldn't use my actual servername and instead needed to use either `localhost` or my IP address, e.g. `ProxyPass / http://localhost/` worked but `ProxyPass / http://example.com/` didn't.

Comment: Resolved: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58111190/1635700

Answer (score 149):

(Answered by the OP in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> The answer is here: http://sysadminsjourney.com/content/2010/02/01/apache-modproxy-error-13permission-denied-error-rhel/

Which is a link to a blog that explains:

> SELinux on RHEL/CentOS by default ships so that httpd processes cannot initiate outbound connections, which is just what mod_proxy attempts to do.

If this is the problem, it can be solved by running:

```
 /usr/sbin/setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

And for a more definitive source of information, see https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/13PermissionDenied

Comment: I think it's not the only reason cause 503. Because the SELinux is disabled. It might be the VirtualHost config error.

Comment: I had the same problem and spent 3 hours trying to fix it until I read your answer. SELinux strikes again!

Answer (score 10):

## Resolve issue Immediate, It's related to internal security

We, SnippetBucket.com working for enterprise linux RedHat, found httpd server don't allow proxy to run, neither localhost or 127.0.0.1, nor any other external domain.

## As investigate in server log found

```
[error] (13)Permission denied: proxy: AJP: attempt to connect to
   10.x.x.x:8069 (virtualhost.virtualdomain.com) failed
```

## Audit log found similar port issue

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1265039669.305:14): avc:  denied  { name_connect } for  pid=4343 comm="httpd" dest=8069 
scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:port_t:s0 tclass=tcp_socket
```

## Due to internal default security of linux, this cause, now to fix (temporary)

```
 /usr/sbin/setsebool httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

## Resolve Permanent Issue

```
/usr/sbin/setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

Answer (score 7):

this worked for me by editing my *.conf file in apache:

```
ProxyRequests     Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
RewriteEngine On

<Proxy http://localhost:8123>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass         /node  http://localhost:8123  
ProxyPassReverse  /node  http://localhost:8123
```

Comment: whats the file name and location ??

Comment: suddenly today apache proxy stopped working just for 443 on the local machine with the IP 1.2.3.4
so changing from `ProxyPass / http:// 1.2.3.4:1234`  to  `ProxyPass / http://localhost:1234`  (equally done for ProxyPassReverse) - I don't know why this happened today. UnattendedUpdate didn't install apache-related stuff, and didn't ran today.

Comment: @Manish the file /etc/apache2/sites-available/your-domain.com-le-ssl.conf or the Centos equivalent.

and yes changing my-dom.com:<port> to localhost:<port> worked for me too on ubunbtu

Answer (score -4):

On CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804, we were able to make this work by editing **/etc/selinux/config** and changing the setting of SELINUX like so:

```
SELINUX=disabled
```

Comment: Disabling security is not going to solve any problem.