# AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: localhost (apache as docker container)

Tags: apache, docker

I am trying to setup apache in front of a server application (JIRA) on my local machine. Somewhat based on:
https://mimiz.github.io/2017/05/18/Configure-docker-httpd-image.html

Both apache and the server application are run as docker containers.

Starting my server application works fine and I can access the web-ui at:

```
http://localhost:8087
```

But when I start apache and try to access it in my browser:

```
http://localhost:80
```

I get:

```
Service Unavailable
```

and when I look at the logs it says:

```
H00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.18.0.5. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Mon Apr 01 09:08:50.408757 2019] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1:tid 140140879032384] AH00489: Apache/2.4.38 (Unix) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Apr 01 09:08:50.409320 2019] [core:notice] [pid 1:tid 140140879032384] AH00094: Command line: 'httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Mon Apr 01 09:09:53.094495 2019] [proxy:error] [pid 8:tid 140140638869248] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8087 (localhost) failed
[Mon Apr 01 09:09:53.094571 2019] [proxy_http:error] [pid 8:tid 140140638869248] [client 172.18.0.1:53110] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: localhost
```

This is **httpd.conf** details I have enabled/added:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
#LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
#LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
...

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.app1.lol
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8087
</VirtualHost>
```

And this is how I start my server application:

```
docker run --network sample-network -p 0.0.0.0:8087:8087 -ti -d --name my-server-container my-server-image
```

And this is how I start apache:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 --network sample-network --name my-apache-container my-apache-image
```

Is the problem my configuration in the **httpd.conf** file or in the docker run commands (or a combination of both)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please refer https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/

It should be configured :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ProxyPass / http://172.17.0.1:8087
</VirtualHost>
```

or :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName localhost
      ProxyPass / http://ip_addressof_my-server-container:8087
</VirtualHost>
```

Use: `docker inspect container_id` to see ip address of container.

Comment: Where did you come up with 172.17.0.1 ?

Comment: it's  IP address of the gateway between the Docker host and the bridge network.

Comment: Ok will that always be that same value? And is that described in some docs somewhere?

Comment: try it then let me know, document here https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/ ,  and I have gotten that issue before.

Comment: this should not be the accepted answer - the address of the container will change. in fact, the initial config is perfectly ok

Answer (score 3):

You can pack everything in a docker compose then you can use the container name:

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ /mylocation/
<Location /mylocation>
    Require all granted
    ProxyPass http://containername:8087/mylocation nocanon
    ProxyPassReverse http://containername:8087/mylocation
</Location>
```

Where  `containername` is the name in the service:

```
version: '2'
services:
  apache:
    image: apache:2.4
    ports:
      - 80:8080
      - 443:8443
  containername:
    image: xxx:x.y.z
    ports:
      - 8087:8087
```

*UPDATE*: If you get issues after the update of a container check:
[Apache proxypass IP addresses cached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33798653/apache-proxypass-ip-addresses-cached)

Answer (score -1):

Face exact same issue, for me in redhat and debian both resolved by below command

`sudo iptables -I INPUT 1 -i lo -j ACCEPT`

Loopback need to enable this way.

Note: Due to some security reason it default disable, we need to enable it